# Insert Null into SQLite3 in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-insert

I am trying to insert a `None` value into a row entry of my db. The table `present` exists

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO present VALUES('test', ?, 9)", "This is a test!")
db.execute("INSERT INTO present VALUES('test2', ?, 10)", None)
```

but I get an error:

```
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

how do I insert a blank value for the second field in the row?

Comment: Did you try with NULL ?

Comment: @opalenzuela passing 'NULL' as a string instead of None worked for me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use a tuple, I.E.:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO present VALUES('test2', ?, 10)", (None,))
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Last time tested on: August 2018

- Python 3.6.1
- Python 2.7.10

---

I'm not sure if it was the case back when the original question was posted, but as of today:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO present VALUES('test', ?, 9)", "This is a test!")
```

throws

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 15 supplied.
```

when ran.

Because `execute()` accepts `sql` — which is sql query to execute, and `parameters` — which is iterable, containing query parameters (currently this is true for both [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute). As string is iterable — it treats it accordingly.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#introduction) clearly state, that Python `None` type correspond to SQLite `NULL` type.

So, correct way to do it would be:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO present VALUES('test2', :null, 10)", {'null':None})

#or

db.execute("INSERT INTO present VALUES('test2', ?, 10)", (None,))
```

Comment: the one with the tuple, (None,) is the correct syntax.

Comment: @redcartel, they both correct see examples under the `# And this is the named style:` for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute).

Comment: Your problem is that "This is a test!" is a string and iterable with 15 elements. `db.execute("INSERT INTO present VALUES('test', ?, 9)", ("This is a test!", ))` would be the correct format since it turns the string into the single element of a tuple, an iterable of the correct size. `["This is a test"] would also work, a list of one element.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the values that you're supplying are meant to be in either a list or a tuple. The second argument is expected the be a collection (array of some kind) that can be iterated over. If you supply a collection it will work, even if that collection only has the one value in it. Another problem arises though in that a string behaves like a collection of characters, and can be iterated over. So when you supply a single string without putting it in a collection itself, it says the "collection" is too big, compared to the number of bindings (question marks). The string "This is a test!" is 15 characters long, and can look like a collection (array) with 15 values when the len() function is used on it. So sqlite3 thinks you've passed a collection as it wants, but the size of the collection doesn't match the number of bindings you've got in the query.